# Simulation in R, for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I got a piece of R code shown as below to find out the values of Y in the last row , each time I run it, R will give 100 values of Y because I set N= 100 as beginning of the simulation...

I am going to simulate it for 500 times to find 500 series of Y. Each simulation contains 100 Y values. As a result, I want to get something like a matrix with 500 rows of simulation, each row contains 100 Y values. I suppose a for loop will help but I did not figure out how to do it? Could anyone help please? Many thanks!!!!!!

```
N = 100
# set up initial values
alpha1 = 8.439e-02
beta1 = 8.352e-01
mu = 7.483e-03 
omega = 1.343e-04
X_0 = -3.092031e-02
sigma_0 = 0.03573968
eps = rt (N,7.433e+00)

# loops
Xn= numeric (N)
sigma= numeric (N)
sigma[1] = sigma_0
Xn[1] = X_0
for (t in 2:N){
  sigma[t] = sqrt (omega + alpha1 * (Xn[t-1])^2 + beta1* (sigma[t-1])^2)
  Xn[t] = sigma[t] * eps[t]
}
Y = mu + Xn
head(Y)
```

Comment: Your algorithm is deterministic (beside of `eps <- rt(..)`), so further simplification is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Put all that in a function `getY <- function(N) { ... }` and use `replicate(500, getY(100))`. So you can do:

```
getY <- function(N) {
  # set up initial values
  alpha1 <- 8.439e-02
  beta1  <- 8.352e-01
  mu     <- 7.483e-03 
  omega  <- 1.343e-04
  X_0    <- -3.092031e-02
  sigma_0 <- 0.03573968
  eps     <- rt(N, 7.433e+00)

  # loops
  Xn    <- numeric (N)
  sigma <- numeric (N)
  sigma[1] <- sigma_0
  Xn[1]    <- X_0
  for (t in 2:N) {
    sigma[t] <- sqrt (omega + alpha1 * (Xn[t-1])^2 + beta1* sigma[t-1])^2)
    Xn[t]    <- sigma[t] * eps[t]
  }
  Y <- mu + Xn
}

X <- replicate(500, getY(100))
```

If you want, you can transpose the result with `t()`, i.e.

```
X <- t(replicate(500, getY(100)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jogo for answering! I tried your code and the matrix I got has 100 rows, 500 columns, but I was looking for the other way around, i.e. 500 rows and 100 columns ? Thanks

Comment: `t(X)` for transpose

Comment: Thanks Jogo again for your great help! Could I please ask a further question regarding to the matrix? I am now have that 500*100 matrix and I would like to do the following code:                                       # r will be each row of the matrix
W0=100
E= 20
constant = exp(cumsum(r))
exp.cum = cumsum(1/constant)
w=const*(W0 - exp.cum)- E
w

Comment: Thanks Jogo again for your great help! Could I please ask another question of the matrix? I am now have that 500*100 matrix and I would like to do the following code where "r" will be each row of the big matrix we got ,basically I want to convert every matrix values in terms of w in this case:  W0=100  ,E= 20 ,constant = exp(cumsum(r)), exp.cum = cumsum(1/constant),w=constant*(W0 - exp.cum)- E .                                                                                  again, I want to run this piece of code 500 times and each row contains 100  w values, possible to do that? Many thanks!

Comment: If you have function which gives you the result for one row vector `r`, e.g. `RowResult <- function(r) { ... }`, then `apply(X, 1, RowResult)` does the calculation for each row of the matrix `X`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jogo. Yes I got the matrix done now. As I can see in this 500 rows matrix, each row has some negative values in it, what I want to do is to find the proportion of negative values in each rows? Also I want the result return 500 proportion of negative values assign each rows? Possible to achieve? Thanks for your help!